# Why can't refs be enclosed?

Tags: reactjs, refs

I'm trying to use react components like that:

```
<Dialog ref='dialog'>
  ....
  <Row ref='item'/>
  ....
</Dialog>
```

Why can't I use `this.refs.item` in my code?
P.S. I solved this by another way, but this question is interested me yet.

Comment: yes because ref is used to access the element not a whole component

Comment: If what you posted is the contents of a render method of a parent component then that would work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can access the mounted DOM element with `this.refs.item` in this way.
Also for your child (row) component.

See [working JSBIN with demo here](http://jsbin.com/bisuhi/1/edit?html,js,output).

How to achieve this depends on the version of react you are using.

In react version 0.13.1 you still need to use `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.item)` to get the DOM element. In later versions (0.14) `this.refs.items` points to:

- React component if you do `<MyComponent ref="foo"/>`
- The DOM element if you put ref in vanilla HTML items eg. `

See also [react documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), with important warnings and advise about when to use or not to use refs.